# @ObservedObject not triggering redraw if in conditional

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RootView: View {
    @ObservedObject var authentication: AuthenticationModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if self.authentication.loading {
                Text("Loading")
            } else if self.authentication.userId == nil {
                SignInView()
            } else {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `@ObservedObject`'s changes doesn't seem to trigger the switch to the other views. I can "fix" this by rendering

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.authentication.loading ? "true" : "false") \(self.authentication.userId ?? "0")")
        }.font(.largeTitle)
        ZStack {
            if self.authentication.loading {
                Text("Loading")
            } else if self.authentication.userId == nil {
                SignInView()
            } else {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
```

and suddenly it starts working. Why does `@ObservedObject` not seem to trigger a rerender if the watched properties are only used in conditionals?

The code for `AuthenticationModel` is:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class AuthenticationModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userId: String?
    @Published var loading = true
    
    init() {
        // TODO: Properly clean up this handle.
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [unowned self] (auth, user) in
            self.userId = user?.uid
            self.loading = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code (at least, partial) for `AuthenticationModel`?

Comment: @NewDev Sure, updated the post.

Comment: I can't reproduce with the code you've shown (I used `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` instead of `Auth`)

Comment: Ohhh interesting. It also works correctly if I use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`. I also tried removing `[unowned self]` and that seems to make it work correctly. Do you know why this might be? I thought this just forced the reference counter to keep the object around.

Comment: I used `unowned` too... did you put a print statement there to see if the closure actually called?

Comment: Yes I did, the closure is definitely called (I also get a valid user id back from the server when rendering the text so I know it roundtrips correctly).

Comment: Hard to say. I'm assuming you're creating an instance `let auth = AuthenticationModel(...)` and passing it in: `RootView(authentication: auth)`? Perhaps the bug is not in the code you've showed.

Comment: Yes I am. I also am not 100% sure the bug is in the code above, but I guess removing `[unowned self]` works for now. Since it's an always-on auth listener it's not too bad. I'm mostly surprised because the app right now is not much more than these views since it's a new project, but I'll maybe come back to this issue and post if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that you aren't creating an instance of AuthenticationModel.
Can you try the following in RootView?:

```
@ObservedObject var authentication = AuthenticationModel()
```